# AWK issue on Bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, awk, automation, timestamp

I need to shortlist the logs between the particular timestamps.

I can achieve it by using the below command.

```
awk '$a>="Feb  5 10:44:*" && $a<="Feb  5 10:54*"' /var/log/xxxx
```

But it's not working in script.

Do I need to assign or mention anything for the variable `$a` in the script?

The script which I used is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#LOG_FILE= "/var/log/messages"

read START_TIME
read END_TIME

#Using AWK
awk '$a>= "$START_TIME" && $a<= "$END_TIME"' /var/log/messages
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `$a` and where is it defined? ... Also you need to pass shell variables to AWK with like `awk -v s="$START_TIME" -v e="$END_TIME" '(... >= s) && (... <= e)' file` ... And avoid ALLCAPS variable names.

Comment: ... and please add a few lines example from any of your logs.

Comment: $a is not declared. Thanks Raffa

Comment: Please show us example input and expected output. You cannot just compare dates the way you are doing, that will compare the strings numerically not the actual dates. For example, `awk '$1 >= "Feb  5 10:44:*"'` would skip `Aug 12 11:32:13`, so this approach just won't work. Next, you probably wanted `$1` instead of `$a`, but you basically need to rewrite everything so we cannot help if we don't know what input you are trying to parse. Please add example input and desired output to the question.

Comment: Even if you set `$a` in your shell, it won't be read with the AWK script inside single quotes and then why use AWK at all in his case to compare external shell variables? ... Why not use something more reliable like  `journalctl --since='2024-2-5 10:44:00' --until='2024-2-5 10:54:00'`  instead of relying on plain text processing to do that.

Comment: To view system logs managed by `systemd-journald`, use ` journalctl` instead or else if you are willing to parse other logs, then please provide us with an example and more info.

Comment: @ArunkumarNKL Please [edit] with an example input file, and the desired output

Comment: @karel how is that dupe relevant? This is about logging, the dupe is about deleted files? 